# PL/SQL Return ROWTYPE from Function

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to write a function that returns a ROWTYPE, but it should only return one record.

Here is my function:

```
FUNCTION f_get_lastest_by_id (p_id IN T_PERSON_ATTRIBUTE.ID%TYPE)
      RETURN T_PERSON_ATTRIBUTE%ROWTYPE
   IS
      out_rec   T_PERSON_ATTRIBUTE%ROWTYPE;
   BEGIN
        SELECT *
          INTO out_rec
          FROM T_PERSON_ATTRIBUTE
         WHERE ID = p_id
      ORDER BY EFFECTIVE_DATE DESC
      OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY;

      RETURN out_rec;
   END;
```

I've also tried

```
FUNCTION f_get_lastest_by_id (p_id IN T_PERSON_ATTRIBUTE.ID%TYPE)
      RETURN T_PERSON_ATTRIBUTE%ROWTYPE
   IS
      out_rec   T_PERSON_ATTRIBUTE%ROWTYPE;
   BEGIN
        SELECT *
          INTO out_rec
          FROM T_PERSON_ATTRIBUTE
         WHERE ID = p_id
      ORDER BY EFFECTIVE_DATE DESC
      LIMIT 1;

      RETURN out_rec;
   END;
```

Non of which will compile.

Comment: there is no `limit` clause in PL\SQL, just remove it

Comment: but that query can return multiple rows, the primary key is compound key, does Oracle just ignore the rest of the records?

Comment: You are selecting by ID, no multiple rows can be here. In case of multiple rows `TOO_MANY_ROWS` exception will occur, in case of no rows we will get `NO_DATA_FOUND` exception

Answer (score 1):

To just return the first record returned by your query do:

```
...
begin
  for rec in (select *
                from t_person_attribute
               where id = p_id
            order by effective_date desc) loop
    return rec; -- just return the first one we find
  end loop;
end;
```

You were trying a `select...into...` with a query that returns more than one record (`order by` notwithstanding). That will not work in PL/SQL. That, and you were trying various SQL keywords that don't exist in the Oracle dialect.